# Problem when trying create new AD sync (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 server located on primary domain.

When I go to Central Administration  Synchronization Connections, and then click create new connection.

Without fail I get this error message:

Cannot navigate to the requested page while user profile synchronization is running. Please wait for the current Synchronization to run to finish.

I've tried restarting the server, restarting both Forefront services. Nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to check the Forefront Identity Manager 2010 for the detailed errors of why it is failing. For that, please take a look at the post here

http://sharepoint-2010-world.blogspot.com/2011/02/cannot-navigate-to-requested-page-while.html